# Cause validation = true not firing server button click event

Tags: asp.net

I have two asp.net buttons in my page.If i make button cause validation false then am able to 
fire button click event on server side but not able to validate text box values(but i need to validate text boxes) using required field validator.

Thank you very much...

Comment: What you say is true and by design. Now, what is your question?

Comment: I want to make button click work for both validation and server side click event

Comment: You might post some code. That helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your form to be validated, you need `CausesValidation` to be true.

For the server side event handler to run, the form needs to be valid, according to the validators you have setup.

Can you post the page markup (including validators), so we can see the issue?

Comment: i mean i need how to make two asp.net buttons work properly if they exist in the same page.I am facing problem on click of buttons
Thank you...